Setting the number of tabs in NvChad
Details of the problem
I like write programs with 4 tab space. Please help.
I don't know if this can be set in Neovim or NvChad, if this is a setting of Neovim, please also help me and also indicate that this is a Neovim setting.
What I tried
I tried adding the following lines to init.lua but it didn't work:
set expandtab
set tabstop=4

Thank you.

You might be trying to write vimscript code in your Lua file (init.lua).
Either write following to use vimscript:
vim.cmd('set expandtab')  
vim.cmd('set tabstop=4')

or use Lua:
vim.opt.tabstop = 4  
vim.opt.expandtab = true


Sorry, but both of the solution doesn't work on my MacOS Sequoia 15.0.1, I hope my MacOS version doesn't affect why these doesn't work.
